# Providing data that is initially undefined, causes cannot read xxx of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react native `FlatList` and the data for it is initially undefined until the user selects a product. It gives error:

> cannot read property 'name' of undefined

about the `renderItem` line of code:

```
  <FlatList
    data={ this.props.selectedProduct ? this.props.selectedProduct.products : [{ name: '' }] }
    renderItem = {({ product }) => <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{product.name}</Text>}
    horizontal = "true"
  />
```

I'm trying to assign it `[{ name: '' }]` if the data is initially undefined so that `product.name` will not throw an error however it isn't making the error go away. How do I get the error to go away? I just want `this.props.selectedProduct.products` to be the data, and not cause the error.

Comment: Try consoling the `product` in the `renderItem` and see if it has a property `name`. Please post what you see in the console.

Comment: I have never worked with FlatList before, but it seems that the problem is that product is undefined. Intuitively it seems that instead of {product.name} you need {product ? product.name : ''}. I might be totally wrong though.

Comment: Hi @user2602079 were you able to find solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The data in `renderItem` must be named `item`:

`renderItem = {({ item }) => <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.name}</Text>}`

Comment: Do you know why ?

Comment: @JulienMalige I THINK it is because ({ item }) is [object destructuring](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/). With object destructuring, you need to name the variables being unpackaged, with the same name as the field they are, in the subsuming object.